# Контроллер домена через интернет c помощью Samba

Tags: samba

Возможно ли сделать Контроллер домена который доступен через интернет средствами Samba ?

Comment: В чем проблема? Да, возможно. Google samba dc

Comment: проблема- запутался с доменами. есть один домен он завязан на статический IP. но для самбы я так понимаю нужен ещё внутренний домен аля company.tld ? тоесть контроллер домена вертится не в локальной сети, а в интернете.

Comment: делал по этой инструкции https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller          локально работает. а как из интернета зайти на DC непонятно..